# Which S-100 systems supported both hard- and soft-sectored 8-inch floppies?

Tags: hardware, s-100

In the late 1970s to early 80s incompatible system software (i.e. MicroSoft Basic and CP/M 1.4) for S100 computers could be released in 8 inch, hard and soft sector, floppy disk formats. In that era what computer systems allowed you simply swap backwards and forwards between these incompatible hard (MicroSoft BASIC) and soft (CP/M 1.4) sector disc formats on the one 8 inch floppy disc drive by a reboot?

Comment: You might largely overestimate the concepts of *compatibility* and *data exchange* requirements for early computing. These came up only relatively late in the CP/M history and with 5 1/4" drives. Most people were absolutely happy when they could read *their own* disks :) Data exchange between computing islands wasn't really a thing.

Comment: There was no data exchange or transfer of information between the IMS hard and soft sector 8 inch floppy disks. System booted in one mode or the other but did not have a dual mode. Hard sector mode was only to access historical documents

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On a "standard" soft-sectored 8" disk, the drive generates one (index) pulse per rotation. On a hard-sectored floppy, the same drive will generate 33 (or 17) pulses (32 sector pulses plus one index pulse which is out-of-sync with the others - The sector and index holes were (on most drives, but not on all) located on the same circumference and picked up by the same sensor).

The [Shugart SA 801 8" floppy drive](https://retrocmp.de/fdd/shugart/801/SA800-801_Service_Manual_1982.pdf)s provide a *separate* sector and index signal (many other drives could do this as well, the SA 801 is only an example. They filter out the one out-of sync pulse and provide it as an index pulse). This makes it possible to build a controller that can read and write both soft and hard sectored disks. (For soft-sectored disks, simply ignore the sector pulses and work on index only). In practice, you could connect the SA 801 drive to either a controller for hard- or soft-sectored (simply don't connect the sector signal) floppies, it would work on both. By doing that, you could even format a hard-sectored floppy as a soft-sectored one (That could, obviously, not be read by a soft-sector-only drive, so this was relatively useless) .

Drive electronics providing the necessary signals, however, is only part of the picture. To be able to handle both hard-sectored and soft-sectored floppies in the same drive, you'd need a controller that can do both (Note a disk controller for a hard-sectored drive can be built *a lot* simpler than for soft-sectored, so from a pure cost perspective, you'd probably prefer hard-sectored).

The [TMS-9909](http://www.bitsavers.org/components/ti/TMS9900/TMS9909_Floppy_Disk_Controller_Preliminary_Data_Manual_Dec82.pdf) is one example of a floppy disk controller that could handle both hard and soft-sectored disks with specific commands (I have yet to find a controller board that used it, though, although we can be sure there was one and I didn't do an exhaustive search. The TMS9909 apparently only had a very limited lifespan). The rest is "only software".... Because the hardware preconditions could all be fulfilled, there were specific "[format conversion boxes](http://ftpmirror.your.org/pub/misc/bitsavers/magazines/Mini-Micro_Systems/198309_Universal_Diskette_Reader.pdf)" that could basically read and write anything and convert between various formats. Modern µ-Controller-based floppy hardware (Fluxcopy/Fluxteen, for example) support both hard and soft-sectored disks.

Comment: I worked for a reseller of Industrial Micro Systems, S100 systems with the Shugart 8in drives and lawyers had purchased it with software for document editing. It was configured with a hard sector controller and MicroSoft software. CP/M 1.4 was a step up but incompatible and it was delivered on soft-sectored disks. As it was S100 system a soft sectored controller could also be installed. Add the TTL logic to switch the drive between hard and soft sectored and you could easily boot into either system. I was unaware that the TMS-9909 existed

Answer (score 2):

I'm not aware of any systems that had configurable hard/soft sector floppy drives.   Typically the floppy drive internal electronics were different, so switching between hard and soft sectoring would be difficult.

Comment: “I’ve never heard of any, because it was hard to do” is a comment than an answer.